# Partitioning a list to a list of smaller lists

Tags: java

I created a utility method `ListUtils.partition(iterable, size)` to partition a potentially large list to a list of smaller lists:

```
public class ListUtils {
    public static <T> List<List<T>> partition(Iterable<T> iterable, int size) {
        if (iterable == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        if (size < 1) {
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (T item : iterable) {
                list.add(item);
            }
            return Arrays.asList(list);
        }
        List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<T> segment = new ArrayList<>(size);
        int i = 0;
        for (T item : iterable) {
            segment.add(item);
            if (++i == size) {
                result.add(segment);
                segment = new ArrayList<>(size);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            result.add(segment);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
public class ListUtilsTest {
    private <T> List<List<T>> partition(Iterable<T> iterable, int size) {
        return ListUtils.partition(iterable, size);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartitionEmpty() {
        assertEquals(Arrays.<List<Object>>asList(), partition(Arrays.asList(), 3));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartitionNull() {
        assertEquals(Arrays.<List<Object>>asList(), partition(null, 3));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartitionZeroSize() {
        List<Integer> orig = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(orig), partition(orig, 0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartitionNegativeSize() {
        List<Integer> orig = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(orig), partition(orig, -3));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartitionInts() {
        assertEquals(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList(1, 2),
                        Arrays.asList(3, 4),
                        Arrays.asList(5)),
                partition(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartitionStrings() {
        assertEquals(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList("1", "2"),
                        Arrays.asList("3", "4"),
                        Arrays.asList("5")),
                partition(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartition_MultipleOfSize() {
        assertEquals(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList(1, 2),
                        Arrays.asList(3, 4)),
                partition(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4), 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartition_Size1() {
        assertEquals(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList(1),
                        Arrays.asList(2),
                        Arrays.asList(3),
                        Arrays.asList(4)),
                partition(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4), 1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPartition_BiggerSize() {
        List<Integer> orig = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        assertEquals(
                Arrays.asList(orig),
                partition(orig, orig.size() + 11));
    }
}
```

Can you improve this? Are there interesting corner cases I might have missed in the tests?

Comment: You could overload the method, with one that takes a `List` instead of an Iterable and return a `List` of subLists of the original list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't agree with your method of handling 0 or negative partition sizes.

A partition is always meant to be a sub-section of a whole. A partition with size 0 is impossible if the whole is non-empty, as there is no way to cut up a whole into sub-sections of size 0. (Note, an empty whole will of course be divisible into partitions of size 0). The same logic applies for negative values. I would think raising a `RuntimeException` such as an `IllegalArgumentException` would make more sense in that context. `null` objects shouldn't be partition-able either, as they are not even empty "wholes".

<strike>Now as for handling sub-section sizes larger than the size of your list, you already define that by having incomplete sub-sections if your sub-section size doesn't divide into your container size. You are missing a test for this, however.</strike>

A final remark: since `Iterable` isn't confined to `Collection`'s measly 2 billion item limit for indexing, you might consider using a `long` for your partition size if you plan to 
use this for large data sets.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the variable `i`, which I believe makes it cleaner (though possibly at the cost of some performance).

```
List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<T> segment = new ArrayList<>(size);
for (T item : iterable) {
    segment.add(item);
    if (segment.size() == size) {
        result.add(segment);
        segment = new ArrayList<>(size);
    }
}
if (segment.size() > 0) {
    result.add(segment);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bug:**

```
assertEquals(partition(Collections.emptyList(), 0).size(), partition(Collection.emptyList(),1).size())
```

fails.

That is, there is a special case in which partitioning a list in partitions equal in size to or greater in size than the size of a list to be partitioned does not equal a result with 1 partition.

Comment: Indeed there is a bug, well spotted! But he bug is not what you describe. The bug is that when `size < 1`, `partition(emptyList, size)` returns an empty-list-within-a-list, but when `size >= 1` it returns an empty list. So the behavior is inconsistent. It would make more sense to standardize on the the second behavior: return an empty list, *never* an empty-list-within-a-list.